# Select column headers that contain a word in SQL

Tags: sql, select, filter, where-clause

I have a large dataset that I only want to select certain column headers that contain the word 'top' in them. I know you can use the WHERE clause to select rows that contain certain words. Is there something you can do with columns in the select field? I've tried a few things but nothing works, so maybe it does not exist?

Comment: You can do this with dynamic sql - you will need to query the system tables to get the column list, then use dynamic sql to build your query.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it - you will need to adjust the values in brackets to your DBs and tables, of course.  This is assuming you are using SQL Server - if not, please edit your question to use tags for the correct DBMS.

```
USE [MyDB];

SELECT a.name 
INTO #columns
FROM sys.all_columns a
LEFT JOIN sys.all_objects b
ON a.object_id = b.object_id
WHERE b.name = '[MyTable]'
AND a.name LIKE '%top%' --select the relevant column names

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'select ' + STUFF((SELECT ',' + name FROM #columns FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') + ' from [MyTable]' --create your SQL statement

PRINT @sql --Look at your SQL statement (optional)
EXEC (@sql) --Run your SQL statement
```